# Express - Multer file upload and save. How to retrieve these back to the front-end

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, html5-video, multer

I am building a React/Node app in which I am uploading video files on the front end, passing them to the backend using Multer and storing them in the backend.
What is the best/correct way to then retrieve these from the storage and pass them back to the video player in the front-end again. React can only access files in the src folder, so I am guessing I need an Http request.
I have done that with express sendFile() and am logging a string for the video file on the front end which I am not sure how to set as the src for the video player.
I would be grateful for any tips.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is probably to server the video as static files.

One of the common ways to do this is using express.js: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/serve-static.html

A simple example is included in their overview page above, which you can modify to point towards the directory you store the uploaded videos in:

```js
var express = require('express')
var serveStatic = require('serve-static')

var app = express()

app.use(serveStatic('public/the_directory_with_the_videos', { index: ['default.html', 'default.htm'] }))
app.listen(3000)
```